# Filter array of Core Data objects with another array of objects with matching property

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, core-data

I have a Core Data object class for images:

```
@objc class Image: NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged var imageData: NSData?
  @NSManaged var recordID: NSNumber?
  @NSManaged var updatedAt: NSDate?  
}
```

I have two different arrays which will contain these objects:

```
var container0 = [Image]()
var container1 = [Image]()
```

What I want to do is write a function that will filter out any **Image** objects in container1 where the **recordID** matches the **recordID** of any object in container2.

Something like:

```
func returnIntersectionByRecordID() -> [Image] {

  var intersection = [Image]()

  for object0 in container0 {
    for object1 in container1 {
      if object0.recordID == object1.recordID {
        intersection.append(object0)
      }
    }
  }
  return intersection
}
```

However, I'd like to do this with a filter instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I come into two steps.
First, get the ids of second array (container2) using map

```
// the will produce array if ids
let ids = container2.map({ return $0.recordId })
```

Then, do filtering

```
let result = container.filter({ ids.contains($0.recordId) })
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great!

Comment: Helped me a lot!